# How to automate a date SELECT to reflect window of historical time-periods?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to refine a query that pulls "x" data based on date window periods.
Let's take this example, one way of doing set of dates is using `BETWEEN` clause.

```
SELECT
    last_close
    date
FROM
    stocks
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2020-11-12' AND '2015-11-12';
```

The only issue is, I want to automate this query so the most recent date is always used as the start of my range(using a "today" function wouldn't work for my dataset), followed a MAX range that would select the last 5 years of date data.

How would I be able to create a query described above?

Edit: This is the query I ended up using, thank you for the help!

```
SELECT symbol, date, adj_close 
FROM api.security_price
WHERE security_price.symbol IN %s AND date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) - interval '5 years' 
ORDER by date;
```

Comment: That query returns nothing, since a date cannot be both >= 2020-11-12 and <= 2015-11-12, which is what `BETWEEN` means. As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparison.html) says: *`a BETWEEN x AND y` is equivalent to `a >= x AND a <= y`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    stuff, 
    date
FROM
    stocks
WHERE
    date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM stocks) - interval '5 years'
```

Which gets the most recent 5 years of data.

Comment: You copied the error of the question statement. `SELECT last_close date`, without a comma, means `SELECT last_close AS date`, making `date` an *output_name*, and those "can be used to refer to the column's value in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses" *(quoting [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST))*.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>=` to be consistent with the use of `BETWEEN` in the question?

Comment: Good discussion, thank you for the help. I updated my OG post with the query I ended up using!

Comment: @andreas - `>= (max_query) + interval '0 years'` would return one day of data. That makes no sense. It should be `>` only.

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah, ok, I can agree with that.